# Changing windows theme in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

I don't know how to explain...Custom windows themes, I can apply them from any of this:

- Open the .theme file easily
- From CMD : call %windir%\Resources\Themes\Shady.theme
- From Powershell : Invoke-Expression "C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\Shady.theme"

but when I use any of this with C# it's breaking the theme - not applying it completely. I tried Verb run as , Tried Making a ps1, bat files and run it with C# but still the same problem... See these screen Shots to understand what I mean

my code:

```
string tokyo1 = "call " + '\u0022' + @"%windir%\Resources\Themes\Tokyo Night.theme" + '\u0022';
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + tokyo1;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
```

[With C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2712.png)
[With cmd,powershell,theme file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if5qj.png)

Comment: You forgot to post the C# code :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Nothing in my code...and I tested 3 not 1 but I added the cmd code to the post (:

Comment: Are you trying to do this company wide?  If so, you might want to set the theme in the Windows Image you deploy to your devices.  This customization can be done with the WICD tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who tried to help.

I Fixed it !

Just Used Windows Forms App
[image: Just Used Windows Forms App]

Not the old one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are just using shell execute from cmd.exe so that you don't need to decide what program should open the .theme file. But that could be done more easyly without calling cmd.exe before just do this:

```
  var windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ("windir");
  var filename = Path.Combine (windir, "Resources\\Themes\\Shady.theme");
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (filename);
```

Comment: The same issue.

Comment: And you checked that %windir% is actualy C:\Windows? or is it possible that you have two different Shady.theme files?

Comment: Yes I am sure and tested with C:\Windows,

Look I think this problems becouse of UltraUXThemePatcher.
I think It's not patching the files correctly